# Aurelia: Do I need to comment .developmentLogging() for production builds?

Tags: aurelia

Using Aurelia CLI, when I run `au build --env prod` do I need to comment out .developmentLogging() in main.js or is that part of the prod build?

I see that debug is set to false in the prod configuration.  Can someone please clarify?  Thanks.

```
  aurelia_project/environments/prod.js

  export default {
    debug: false,
    testing: false
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply add the following to your `main.js`:

```
import environment from "./environment";

if (environment.debug) {
  aurelia.use.developmentLogging();
}
```

This way development logging will only be used in the debug environment.

Comment: Thanks!  That works when you add "import environment from './environment';" to main.js.